# MailApp.sendEmail not working for multiple recipients when values fetched from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some email addresses in a google sheet to whom a mail is to be sent.
When I fetch these addresses from the sheet in the code and try to send the email I get the error "Invalid email address xyz@mydomain.com,pqr@mydomain.com"

Used below function

```
        sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
```

However when I manually write the email addresses in the code
for eg

```
   var recipients='xyz@mydomain.com,pqr@mydomain.com';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, message, {attachments: 
    [attach]});
```

It works fine !!

### My code

```
 var emailTo = contacts.getRange(1, 1, numRows, 1).getValues();
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});
 //or
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo.toString(), subject, message, {attachments: 
 [attach]});
```

Its not working !!!

I cant understand how is emailTo.toString() and 'xyz@mydomain.com,pqr@mydomain.com' different.

Used "if" condition to compare these two and its returning false. When I print these two they look exactly the same.

Comment: Where is `numRows` defined in your script? Just tested all of these myself and they work fine once I had it defined correctly.

Comment: Its defined in the script, did not share that part here.
It has the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set up a test sheet & script for this.

Here's my test sheet example:

[image: test sheet]

This is the script:

```
function stringMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('mail-test');

  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getValues().length;

  var m1 = 'abc@mydomain.com,def@mydomain.com,ghi@mydomain.com';
  var m2 = sh.getRange(1, 1, numRows, 1).getValues();
  var m3 = m2.toString();

  Logger.log(m1);
  Logger.log(m2);
  Logger.log(m2.toString());
  Logger.log(m3);

  if (m1 == m2.toString()) {
    Logger.log('true');
  }
  if (m1 == m3) {
    Logger.log('also true');
  }
  if (m3 == m2.toString()) {
    Logger.log('still true');
  }
}
```

As you can see I ran some basic if statements to check if they are considered the same, if so then write a log entry.

From the log output:

```
[19-05-13 09:38:23:178 BST] abc@mydomain.com,def@mydomain.com,ghi@mydomain.com
[19-05-13 09:38:23:179 BST] [[abc@mydomain.com,def@mydomain.com], [ghi@mydomain.com]]
[19-05-13 09:38:23:179 BST] abc@mydomain.com,def@mydomain.com,ghi@mydomain.com
[19-05-13 09:38:23:180 BST] abc@mydomain.com,def@mydomain.com,ghi@mydomain.com
[19-05-13 09:38:23:180 BST] true
[19-05-13 09:38:23:181 BST] also true
[19-05-13 09:38:23:181 BST] still true
```

As you can see, variable `m1` which is just a string of email addresses is considered the same as `m2`, which is your `getValues().toString()`  used in your `MailApp.sendEmail()`. I also defined `m3` which was just `m2.toString()` defined separately to make sure that worked too.

After this testing we can determine that it's most likely the values in your spreadsheet that are causing the error, you should double check for any extra spacing or strange characters.

As long as you're pulling `getValues()` correctly and then converting it using `toString()` you shouldn't be having any issues with this.

Comment: I deleted the cell which contained the email and in the new cell I entered the email address and it worked. Still not sure what exactly was the issue but it was something related to data/cell formatting/invisible strange characters etc

Comment: Yeah, sheets can be strange like that sometimes. I'm glad your issue is resolved.

Comment: My code was correct . Accepting your answer as you mentioned that it can be a data issue.